# tmux split-window without changing focus

Tags: tmux

Is there any way to split a window in tmux without changing the current focus?

I'm running a script inside one of my tmux panes that occasionally runs "tmux split-window ..." with some command that takes a minute to complete and MAY request input.

I can end up trying to type input into one of the tmux panes but in the middle of my typing, the original pane executes "tmux split-window ..." and (mid word) my cursor shifts to the new pane, and I end up typing part of the input into the wrong pane.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Note**: this answer is correct, but obsolete. The right way is to use `-d` flag for `split-window` command. I'm leaving this answer as a demonstration how to do some yak shaving with tmux.

A `split-window` command flag provided by tmux would be the right solution for this. <strike>Unfortunately tmux does not provide such command flag</strike>. **Update**: there is a `-d` `split-window` flag that does this.

- The simple solution is to immediately switch to previous pane after `split-window`:

  ```
  tmux split-window
  tmux last-pane
  ```

  This can be also written as a one liner:

  ```
  tmux split-window\; last-pane
  ```

  The downside of this solution is that *theoretically* you might end up writing a character in the wrong window if you type it in time interval between `split-window` and `last-pane` command execution.
- Here another approach with the downside that it's more complex.

  Create a new window in the background and get the `pane_id` of this window (note how this command is wrapped in `$(...)` because we want it executed in a subprocess:

  ```
  pane_id=$(tmux new-window -d -P -F "#{pane_id}")
  ```

  Now join the window we just created with the window where your cursor is located (will not change cursor focus):

  ```
  tmux join-pane -b -t "$pane_id"
  ```

  Add `-h` to the `join-pane` above if you want a horizontal split.

I recommend taking the first approach for it's simplicity. It's highly unlikely you'll have any practical issues with it.

Comment: D'oh, yes it would. I missed it because `-d` flag wasn't documented for `split-window` command (although it is on the list of flags). Please provide this as an answer, I'll update my post to indicate it's obsolete.